# c++ dynamic arrays in class

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create an example with dynamic arrays in class in order to user destructor and copy constructor.

The idea of the program is the following. I have class Labtest with two private fields. ntest an integer which holds the number of tests and values which is a dynamic array with ntest elements.

I added method add which extends dynamic array by one and add the argument to the last position.

I added a friend function max which returns the max element of the dynamic array (which takes a call by value object) in order to demonstrate the necessity of copy constructor.

I overloaded << in order to print the objects.

I added default constructor, destructor, copy constructor.

The code i wrote so far is

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Labtest {
public:
    Labtest();
    Labtest(const Labtest& a);
    ~Labtest();
    friend int max(Labtest a);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Labtest& lab);
    void add_value(int a);
private:
    int ntests;
    int *values;
};

int main()
{
    Labtest chem;
    chem.add_value(10); chem.add_value(20);
    cout << chem;
    cout << "the maximum is " << max(chem) << endl;
    cout << chem;
    return 0;
}

Labtest::Labtest() : ntests(0), values(NULL)
{
}

Labtest::Labtest(const Labtest & a) : ntests(a.ntests)
{
    values = new int(ntests);
    for (int i = 0; i < ntests; i++)
        values[i] = a.values[i];
}

Labtest::~Labtest()
{
    ntests = 0;
    delete[] values;
}

void Labtest::add_value(int a)
{
    int *newvalues = new int(ntests+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < ntests; i++)
        newvalues[i] = values[i];
    newvalues[ntests] = a;
    delete[] values;
    values = newvalues;
    ntests++;
}

int max(Labtest a)
{
    int m = a.values[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < a.ntests; i++)
        if (m < a.values[i])
            m = a.values[i];
    return m;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream & out, const Labtest& lab)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lab.ntests; i++)
        out << lab.values[i] << " ";
    out << endl;
    return out;
}
```

I am getting an out of heap bounds error in Visual Studio. Even if i comment the call to the max function.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `new int(10)` makes an array with the value `10`. `new int[10]` makes an array of 10 `int`s.

Comment: You should be aware that `int max(Labtest a)` makes a copy of `a` every time it's called. You should use `const Labtest & a` instead.

Comment: You are right! I can't believe such a mistake!!! Moreover, as for the copy of a, everytime the max is finished destructor will free to memory of a. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the extra copy isn't technically a problem. Though it's important to learn when when to pass by reference, when to pass by value and rather or not a parameter should be `const`. In this case, `Labtest` only contains `int`s and is probably never going to contain too many values. But in practice, needlessly copying containers is a bad habit.

Comment: Thanks i just used in order to demonstrate the need of a copy constructor. Please make an answer in order to give you a vote. :-)

Comment: In this case, the need for a copy constructor is implicit. Because your class has a raw pointer which owns an object (it's responsible for calling `delete` on it) it falls under the [rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). The implicit copy constructor will not do the right thing and must be overwritten or deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new int(10)` makes an `int` variable with the value 10. `new int[10]` makes an array of 10 `int`s. From the context, it's clear that you intended to use the second form. The use of the first form would lead to undefined behavior when you called `delete[] values;` (since `values` would not be an array) or when you accessed any elements beyond the first.

Answer (score 0):

When you're allocating arrays you should do `int *newvalues = new int[ntests+1];` using brackets instead `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Template class sdt::vector just provides the functionallity you need - without involving you in details of memory management.
But in case want to practice memory management, I should remind you of 3 notes:

1. Syntax of array new operator is `new type_spec[n]` not new `type_spec(n)`. The syntax that you have used, just allocates a single object and initializes it with n. So disposing it with array delete operator leads to UB.
2. It is safer to nullify the pointer after deleting.
3. When defining any class that aquires system resources (heap memmory in this case), it is often nessary to define following functions:

   Copy contructor.

   Swap function.

   Move constructor, normally in terms of swap.

   Move/copy assinment operator or both, in terms of swap.

   Destructor in terms of swap.

Otherwise - sooner or later - violating 1 or more of the resource handling rules occurs due to forgetting implicit temporary object generation or other semantics. And abnormal behavior will take place.

Comment: Your second point is wrong. Nullifying a pointer after deleting doesn't make anything safer at all.

Comment: The least it can do is guarding against double deleting. If becomes a habit, triggers a -hopefully - early runtime memory exception in cases otherwise a silent reference to deleted object error might bug the program. There is more, but I cant put it in a char[600].

Comment: It cannot guard against the most dangerous form of double deleting, and that is when there are more pointers to the same object in your program. It also cannot be expected to trigger anything, because dereferencing `nullptr` is undefind behaviour anyway. All it accomplishes is giving you a false sense of security and burning CPU cycles :)

Comment: Am I going to give a full implementation? This is not enough but it is the least one can do.By the way, why should anyone expose the raw pointer?
About the case of null; on more than one pc platform dereferencing throws memory exception. Using raw pointers has always been walking on the tip of a blade; That is why it is preferable to minimize manipulation and explicitly use delete only once - in the destructor.

Comment: If you delete only in the destructor, then setting the pointer to null is even more meaningless. Nobody can access the pointer after the destructor is finished. I am not arguing for raw pointers, I just argue that setting a pointer to `nullptr` after delete doesn't make anything safer.

Comment: And it does not use cpu cycles. It will be removed by the optimizer, if the programmer doesn't furthur use the nullified pointer.

Comment: And who says optimisation is always enabled? Even if you optimise everything in shipped builds, you burn CPU cycles during testing. Not that it matters much; the fact that it adds an additional meaningless line to the source code may be worse.

Comment: It is by no means meaningless; does what it is designed to do. And it is worth that testing cycle, because it removes lots of cycles wasted consuming noticeable human time and energy for debugging.